# How can I use custom handler in Retrofit2 as I do in 1.9.1

Tags: android, json, jackson, retrofit, retrofit2

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(WILD_DIVERSITY_END_POINT)
    .setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler())
    .setConverter(new JacksonConverter())
    .setClient(new OkClient(okClient))
    .setLogLevel(Constants.DEBUG ? 
        RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : 
        RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE);
```

this is my custom handler class

```
public abstract class RestCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    public abstract void failure(String restErrors, boolean networkError);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        String restErrors = null;
        boolean networkError = false;
        Throwable throwable = error.getCause();
        if ( throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException || throwable instanceof  ConnectException || throwable instanceof RestClient.NetworkErrorException) {
            restErrors = "It seems you are not connected to internet or your data connection is slow or our server is down. Please try again later.";
            networkError = true;
        }  else if(error.getResponse()!=null&&error.getResponse().getBody()!=null){
            String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
            if (json != null){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("errors");
                    restErrors = jsonArray.getString(0);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    restErrors = "Unknown error occured!";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        if(restErrors==null&&error!=null&&error.getCause()!=null) restErrors = error.getCause().getLocalizedMessage();
        failure(restErrors,networkError);
    }
```

I want to use this class to add in retofit2.0 settings
this is my retrofit2.0 setup

```
public static GitApiInterface getClient() {
        if (gitApiInterface == null) {

            OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            okClient.interceptors().add(logging);

            Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(rest.JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            gitApiInterface = client.create(GitApiInterface.class);
        }
        return gitApiInterface ;
    }
```

I wanted to add custom error handler in Retrofit 2.0 as I used to add in Retrofit 1.9.0 like this `setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler())`
so that I can handle the `onFailure` results.

Comment: Take a look at how to add **interceptors** and read the [changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).